# Explanation of a word in a footnote at the bottom of the page

Tags: header-footer, footnotes

I want to provide an explanation for a word as a footnote at the bottom of the page in which the word appears. For instance, in the main text, I would have

> Here is my word¹

and, in a footnote at the bottom of the page, I would explain the word in question:

> ¹ explain it here...

How can I do that?

Comment: Try to add a `\footnote{explain it here}`

Comment: and what about the small number beside the word? how can i add it?

Comment: It works Thaaaaaanks alot